# time() with different timezones

Tags: php

How can i get user's local time using php time() or there is another way to do it?
Which means it will be in their timezone.

I need to calculate time ago with user's local time, here's a nice script i found for the time ago function:

```
<?php
function timeago($time)  
    {  
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");  
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");  

    $now = time();

    $difference     = $now - $time;  
    $tense         = "ago";  

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++)   
        {  
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];  
        }  

    $difference = round($difference);  

    if($difference != 1)   
        {  
        $periods[$j].= "s";  
        }  

    return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense";  
    }  
?>

<?php

$date = strtotime('2012-04-15 07:41:03');
$datep = timeago($date);

echo $datep;
?>
```

from the above script , i use the time() but it only gets my server time not the local time at my side. how can i get my local time(user's local time)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/how-can-i-determine-a-web-users-time-zone ??

Comment: What is the users timezone? Unless yo don't tell your PHP script, it won't know so it takes the servers time (`$time = time();`) or you pick the GMT/UTC time (`$time = (int) gmdate('U');`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's always possible to get local time from the sever without the client passing you information - javascript being a good example.  The way I do it (not my idea, read it somewhere) is to set a local time cookie with javascript and get PHP to read the cookie and then use that data with date_default_timezone_set().  I think that's the only bulletproof answer and it works fine for me.

EDIT: I read it from http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this would be client-side. Use Javascript's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) functions, and send them to PHP.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, it is the most effective method as long as it is combined with cookies. +1

Answer (score 0):

There's not a server-based/PHP method for getting local time. You have to get it from the client via Javascript.  Google "bitbucket timezone detect" and use it to set a "local_timezone" cookie that you can read from PHP and set via date_default_timezone_set()