# PHP returns incorrect timezone. Why?

Tags: php, timezone

I follow IST (Indian Standard Time).

So when I try to print that in PHP, I should get my timezone. But PHP is outputting wrong timezone.

Does anyone have any idea regarding this??

```
$mytimezone=date_default_timezone_get();
echo $mytimezone;
```

gives

```
Europe/Paris
```

as output.

Comment: You should set the correct timezone with `date_default_timezone_set();`

Comment: is this your code on any server ? May be taking its timezone

Comment: your server time is probably set to `Europe/Paris`, you can set the timezone at runtime using `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');`

Comment: It is localhost @Khushboo

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of two things. Either your server is hosted on a European server, or that your system clock has the Europe timezone set.
you can manually set the timezone with this line. Else check your hosting platform's settings.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Comment: This is a good way. But if my page is used by users from various parts of the world...so their timezone varies. Then setting this ain't a good reason. In a situation like that, how can I tackle this problem??? @Matosha

Comment: If your site is dependant on an active users timezone, then look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone)
@TheJoker