# how to display strtotime in local time zone

Tags: php, timezone

working with a chat box where getting the msg time with raw as far I've got this `$msg_time = strtotime($row["date_time"]);` which is showing the strtotime values correctly. now getting confused how to show this with local timezone

Comment: You need to display server or client  timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server Timezone**

```
     <?php
        // set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime('2014-02-21')) . "timezone: " . date_default_timezone_get();
```

**Client Timezone**

file where you want to display the timezone

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- javascript/jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <?php
        session_start();
        echo isset($_SESSION['time']) ? $_SESSION['time'] : "error";
    ?>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var visitortime = new Date();
        var visitortimezone = "GMT " + -visitortime.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "timezone.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1",
            data: 'time=' + visitortimezone,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

timezone.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['time'] = $_POST['time'];
```

Comment: what if the local timezone is America/Vancouver is this correct?
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');

Comment: And I dont want to echo it, I want to convert it as $msg_time how can I do this?

Comment: `$msg_time = date_default_timezone_get();`

Comment: Still ambiguous. what are you want to do with the timezone?

Comment: `elseif($_POST["fetch"]==1)
 {
  $results = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT user, message, date_time FROM (select * from shout_box ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) shout_box ORDER BY shout_box.id ASC");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
  {
   
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');
   
  $msg_time = date('h:i A M d',strtotime($row["date_time"])); 
   
echo '<div class="shout_msg"><time>'.$msg_time.'</time><span class="username">'.$row["user"].'</span> <span class="message">'.$row["message"].'</span></div>';
  }`I want to show the time in my localtime zone instead of server time

Comment: ahhh you are talking about client's time zone. you have to use Javascript. Remeber PHP is server side and JS client side, please read this old question that explain exactly what are you trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone

Comment: so what should I put here to show the time in local timezone?

Comment: Did you read the link? if you did and you follow the instructions you should display $_SESSION['time']; But you need to follow the instruction.  Otherwise, you are going to get blank

Comment: I know it is really late, so i did it for you

Comment: this is the script http://dnetbd.com/shout_php.txt where It's happening, please tell me how can I implement your solution with my script.

Comment: help please. I'm stuck here.