# how to set date and time based on users location

Tags: php, timezone

I want to set date and time based on users location.

I used the following php code to set the date and time in indian standard time.

how to find the users timezone.

```
<?php
    $timezone = "Asia/Kolkata";
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $time=date("h:i a");
    $date = date("M d,Y");
?>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: @ssh is there a solution to do this

Comment: date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

Comment: @glorfindel for your answer I have to get users details. my site is like a open site.

Comment: @olly Tenerife the user who opens in america will see indian standard time. I needed to show him american standard time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the timezone from a JavaScript code, and then transmit it to your server.

Examples can be found here:
[get user timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone)