# php - date_default_timezone_get() - wrong result

Tags: php

How do I check user's timezone using php?

I tried `date_default_timezone_get()` but it shows "Europe/Berlin" while my actual timezone is "Europe/Warsaw".
Is there any other way to check it using php?
Thanks.

Comment: PHP can't get the timezone directly from a web browser for your users, you need to use front-end coding to do this (e.g. javascript) and then send that information to your PHP application

Comment: any example please @MarkBaker?

Comment: you can use geo api or javascript. see: http://snippets.khromov.se/get-visitor-local-time-sunrise-and-sunset-time-by-ip-with-maxmind-geoip-and-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Warsaw' )`
these must be included in all your php files, if you are in MVC pattern in your config or bootstrap file.

If it is possible You can also change your php.ini file :
http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.configuration.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I want to check user's timezone, not server's.

Comment: oh! i see, but date_default_timezone_get() does not retrieve the user timezone but gets the "default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script" - PHP
maybe this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone