# Laravel convert Session variable to integer

Tags: php, string, laravel, session

```
$offset = "<script>document.write(new Date().getTimezoneOffset().toString());</script>";
Session::set("offset", $offset);
$offset=Session::get("offset");

echo intval($offset);
```

I am trying to convert timezone to integer. intval output is always 0.

Comment: Err, do you put your code inside quotes like that?

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first question posted here @frz3993

Comment: Ok, what your code implies is that you are trying to get the integer representation of a string containing alphanumericals (`"<script>document....`). Simply put, how can you represent `abcd.><>` in integer form ?

Comment: You are trying to get a timezone by javascript in PHP? That's not how you should be doing it.

Comment: Can you tell me how  I should get time offset ?

Comment: @frz3993 If I echo $offset it would show me  -120 which is my time offset.
So , I am trying to get integer representation of -120
I want the value to be integer in order to make some operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Session::set("time", time());
```

Then you can get your offset in next request:

```
$time=Session::get("time");
echo $time;
```

If you need to use TimeZone then you can use Carbon instance since you're using Laravel.

```
$time = Carbon::now();
$timeZone = $time->timezone;
Session::put('timezone', $timeZone);
```

and then retrieve the timezone from session....

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Carbon::now() gets the time (Europe/London) timezone which is UTC+0
I need to get the timezone depending on the client. So I would probably need to get it with javascript.

Comment: Carbon::now() shows the server timezone right? It doesn't know anything about the end-user's timezone. I would need client timezone.

Comment: oh that's right. Then you need to implement something like the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607444/2951316.

Answer (score 0):

```
$offset = "<script>document.write(new Date().getTimezoneOffset().toString());</script>";
Session::set("offset", $offset);
```

This means=

```
Session::set("offset", "<script>document.write(new Date().getTimezoneOffset().toString());</script>");
```

So your offset value is just a string "< script>document.write(new Date().getTimezoneOffset().toString());< /script>"

Your question should be how to get user timezone which is duplicate.

[Determine a User's Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone)

[get user timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone/5607444#5607444)

Comment: this means that I cannot echo result of the script to the php variable.
thanks. Unfortunately I am not able to like your answers:))

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped you out :)