# How to keep JavaScript variable value in PHP session variable on the same page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using JavaScript to get the user timezone name. I want that timezone name into PHP session variable in the same page. JavaScript is client side and PHP is server side. How will it be possible? Are there any ways to this?

Comment: Use JS to create a session variable? And check for that using PHP?

Comment: to achieve that, i have tried with ajax request to same page... but this is not a good practice right? @Mohammad

Comment: You might consider moving this timezone information between browser and Server using a cookie

Comment: @RatnaRaju that'd be the only way to pass a javascript variable into php, since like you said, javascript is client-side an php is server-side. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an ajax post and post the value you want to a php file and there update the php session variable like

`$_SESSION['timezone'] = $_POST['timezone']`