# get user's timezone equal to moment guess in nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, momentjs

Nodejs can detect user's timezone with moment js guess function, but php can't, why ?? if php can then please give me a brief and if I have wrong information about moment in nodejs please explain me how does moment guess works.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP is a `server-sided` language, while Javascript is `client-sided` - that's why you can't do it in PHP like you can in JavaScript.

However, this question is most likely to be a duplicate of [get user timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone).