# How to get the accurate timezone in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the time of the user and have been experimenting with timestamp but found it to display inaccurate time unless I set the timezone to that particular state but this method seems tedious for setting all the states in the world.. I have seen some website where they allow the user to select their GMT timezone.... how is this done in php?

Comment: What you mean with "inaccurate" time?

Comment: By "inaccurate" do you mean server time? Your best bet would be to use JavaScript to get the client's time.

Comment: Welcome. PHP is run server-side, you'll have a hard time getting "the time of the user" (client-side) using PHP.

Comment: Visit this url for get timezone https://stackoverflow.com/a/10103105/9266700

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> The JavaScript Date object supports a number of UTC (universal)
>   methods, as well as local time methods. UTC, also known as Greenwich
>   Mean Time (GMT), refers to the time as set by the World Time Standard.
>   The local time is the time known to the computer where JavaScript is
>   executed. Invoking JavaScript Date as a function (i.e., without the
>   new operator) will return a string representing the current date and
>   time.