# PHP - Get device/browser local time in Unix

Tags: php, browser, time

I need to get the end users device time echo'ed on a page, ideally this would be by

Q1) discover end users time zone,

2) I will then get the current unix time using `$currenttimeunix = time();`

Q3) adjust for time zone difference

2 I can do, so it's Q1 & Q3 I need help with

Comment: Why not use JavaScript to post the time? That would solve all the problems at once

Comment: Use javascript/ajax, then transform the data in server side. The end user clock may be wrong so you need to be aware of this.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I think the likelihood is higher that the user is using a VPN which will offset the time, than the time on the device is incorrect. But that is my guess

Comment: Sure @Andreas , it can be different/inaccurate by many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can do nothing with user's device/browser/whatever through php since it's javascript (or any client side language) responsibility.

PHP runs in the server not in the user's device. `time()` will always give you the server's time in epoch never the user's.

For more details on how to get the user's local time by javascript (using jquery) check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607444/3332676). Though you can never trust it as @FelippeDuarte and @Andreas discussed it under your question in comments.

---

**Update**
I copy the most important parts of the mentioned answer.

On the PHP page where you are want to have the timezone as a variable, have this snippet of code somewhere near the top of the page:

```
<?php    
    session_start();
    $timezone = $_SESSION['time'];
?>
```

This will read the session variable "time", which we are now about to create.

On the same page, in the `<head>` section, first of all you need to include jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Also in the `<head>` section,, paste this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if("<?php echo $timezone; ?>".length==0){
            var visitortime = new Date();
            var visitortimezone = "GMT " + -visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://example.com/timezone.php",
                data: 'time='+ visitortimezone,
                success: function(){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Create a new file called **timezone.php** and point to it with the above url

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['time'] = $_GET['time'];
?>
```

If this works correctly, it will first load the page, execute the JavaScript, and reload the page.  You will then be able to read the $timezone variable and use it to your pleasure!  It returns the current UTC/GMT time zone offset (GMT -7) or whatever timezone you are in.