# How can I parse a string using strtotime() for different timezones

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have an input string that will look something like

"Monday 2:00 pm" and I need to get a timestamp representation of this, but I cant figure out how to introduce different timezones.

For example right now I just simply do

```
 $name = "Monday";
 $time_string = "2:00 pm";

 $time_stamp = strtotime("$name $time_string");
```

which will get me a timestamp but say someone in 'America/New_York' inputs this v someone in 'America/Los_Angeles' the timestamps should be different correct?

Comment: Yes, the times will be different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get client's timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can set the default timezone before you call strtotime:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

But the UNIX epoch is always in UTC, so I'm not sure this makes any difference to the timestamp:

```
// New York
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo time(); // 1322309733

// London
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo time(); // 1322309733
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Need to rethink this one.

Comment: While that will allow you to change the timezone (globally, which is unnessary), it still wont tell you what timezone that date was entered in.

Comment: @Gordon precisely. I was referring to the question: "timestamps should be different correct?" -> The timestamps will not be different, since they are always in UTC. My answer might be a bit long winded! :)