# I need php function to get time from browser not server

Tags: php

I am programming forum script and I have problem in time because the server time defrent from my country time;
I tried to use this own function but the problem transferred to my friends in other countries hhhhh:

```
function ftime($time, $reg = false)
{
    $time = $time ;
    $mytime = protect($_SESSION['mytime']);
    $time = $time + $mytime;
    $time2 = time() - 3600  + $mytime;
}
```

** note : this not all of my function

Comment: You need javascriot for this

Comment: @JohnConde --> how to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side language and can not directly get client's Time. You will have to check for timezones and write your own function with a little help from client side scripts.

Comment: thank you,, is there a free ready function or class for that??

Comment: Yeah there will be plenty. Just google 'javascript get client time' and you will get many

Answer (score 0):

exactly, you need some help from js to determine the timezone.

check this ones:

[How to get client's timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone)

[Determine a User's Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone)