# Time() not working with PDO

Tags: php, date, pdo

I have been trying to get this code working for about half an hour and for the life of me, I can't. I've been able to echo the time, but when I try implementing it into my PHP parser, it just returns all 0's. I've tried many different ways, but the code only reflects one way I've tried.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $date = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time());
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=x', 'x', 'x');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO zzz (x, x1, x2, reply_date) VALUES (:x, :x1, :x2, :date1)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':x', $_POST['yyy']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':x1', $_POST['qqq']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':x2', $_POST['ppp']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date1', $date);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `reply_date`column is a DateTime Column, you have to make sure the date passed is in [a format recognizable by your database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html). Otherwise it will insert 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for the date.

But if you are going to insert the current time anyways, just change your insert from

```
INSERT INTO zzz (x, x1, x2, reply_date) VALUES (:x, :x1, :x2, :date1)
```

to

```
INSERT INTO zzz (x, x1, x2, reply_date) VALUES (:x, :x1, :x2, NOW())
```

That will take care of it. You can then easily format this date to whatever you need in PHP when you fetch it from the database, e.g.

```
$dt = new DateTime($row['date']); 
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y h:i:s a')
```

or the procedural way:

```
echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', strtotime($row['date']);
```

If you need a timezone with that, check out:

- [Timezone conversion in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php/2505687#2505687) and
- [How to get client's timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone/1913578#1913578)