# How to find the difference between time in my country and time in another country in PHP

Tags: php, time

In our script we need to provide a facility to people to schedule a meeting on a specific time , how can we avoid the time difference issue in two countries . In other words if a person from India request meeting time on 10AM (Indian time ) , we need to show that request in the person in other country in their own time ( It will not be 10AM in the other country )

how can I do that ?

Comment: What if "another country" spans in 11 timezones?

Comment: I have updated the question , kindly refer that

Comment: What if "another country" spans in 11 timezones? (I haven't updated my comment, since you didn't answer)

Comment: Yes that is my problem , what I need is if a person from India say 10am , how can we show the corresponding time in another country

Comment: What if "another country" spans in 11 timezones?

Comment: Generaly you could just store as Unix-Timestamp and display depending on the users local timezone....you'll have the problem  of determining the users local timezone anyway. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [`geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-time-zone-by-country-and-region.php) for achieving this, You just need to pass the country and region and can adjust/notify users in different timezone about 
the actual time.

You may refer this [ARTICLE](http://jules.boussekeyt.org/2010/deal-with-timezone-php.html) here also

Answer (score 0):

@Sun Don't sure. But I think this will works well, test this

```
$date = date_create(null, timezone_open('Europe/London'));
$tz = date_timezone_get($date);
$time= timezone_name_get($tz);
date_default_timezone_set($time);
$get= date('h:i A') ;
echo $get;
```

Good Luck!