# PHP: Get client PC timezome of logged in user from

Tags: php

I was wondering whether to use APIs or Javascript to get the timezone of client system or simple store **timezone** of logged in user in database. Could you please suggest me which is better and feasible?

Context:
employees will be logging in to site from different countries. So their requests will have to be solved in a time bound manner. Here datetime calculation is required.

Thanks!

Comment: [Have you seen this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeah, but i wanted to know which is a better solution. so thought to raise it (whether o use javascript or API or simply store inDB?)

Comment: Depends what you want to do with it, you'll have to provide some context

Answer (score 1):

You can send it to the server together with the client login. Simply add a hidden input in which to write the zone/time with javascript. And then store it in session or database.

Do it on each login because the client may switch zones.

This solution is better for me - more simple and straight forward.

If you prefer ajax javascript solution check this question: [how-to-get-clients-timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

PHP only display server side time.

For client side time you need to use javascript.

JS Code:

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Sorry, by mistake was added.