# Javascript and PHP date formatting gives different values

Tags: javascript, php, date, time

When I do this in php

```
echo date("Y/m/d",786668400);
```

I get `1994/12/06`

but when I do this in javascript:

```
console.log(new Date(786668400*1000).getDate() + "." + 
           (new Date(786668400*1000).getMonth() + 1) + "." + 
            new Date(786668400*1000).getFullYear());
```

I get `5.12.1994`

The date is wrong, it should be 6.12.1994

what am I doing wrong here?

```js
    console.log(new Date(786668400 * 1000).getDate() + "." +
      (new Date(786668400 * 1000).getMonth() + 1) + "." +
      new Date(786668400 * 1000).getFullYear());
```

Comment: `5.12.1994` is correct as that timestamp points to `Mon 5 Dec 1994 23:00`. It's possible your PHP code is applying a timezone offset which is affecting the output

Comment: The code you share is plain javascript, not jquery

Comment: I get the 6th at 11:50CET

Comment: Save unix timestamp in UTC timezone and check with javascript which timezone is used and convert given date to UTC.

Comment: `new Date(786668400 * 1000)` is equivalent to 1994-12-05T23:00:00.000Z, any difference is due to the application of the host system timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

Your unix timestamp gives you the wrong date, because in UTC time it's `05.12.1994 23:00:00`. In *my* local timezone, it's `06.12.1994 00:00:00`

Try changing your timezone.

Comment: right, so how do i make the time not matter? because this is from a birthdate so i don't need the time and it looks like that's what's causing me problems..

Comment: You shouldn't be storing dates with no time part as timestamps, if coming from a database then use a ``DATE`` datatype

Comment: Well you could change with PHP your timezone to your local timezone (to be sure you are not using UTC). See at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @cfreear sorry that part can't be changed

Comment: Guys downvoting, but I just gave the answer to the given question. *laugh*

Comment: @MattBackslash I think you may be downvoted because you didn't actually give an answer, just a hosted image that may not be hosted in 6 months time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change it.

Comment: Also; changing your php timezone isn't really the solution as that would require all clients to reside in the same timezone.

Comment: @cfreear can the default timezone be changed dynamically according to the client's timezone?

Comment: @SuzanneEdelmanCreoconcept yes. There's already a post about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone