# What is exactly Epoch time? Convert epoch in client timezone in PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unix-timestamp

My questions are:

- What is exactly unix epoch timestamp ?
- How can i use it in PHP to convert ?
- How can i convert base on client timezone ?

I tried many samples to get client timezone:

- [How to get client's timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone)
- [How to detect user's timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525617/how-to-detect-users-timezone)

But I had no chance.

I tried this at last to get client timezone but no chance again :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser    client
  var timezone = tz.name(); //'Asia/Kolhata' for Indian Time.
  $.post("url-to-function-that-handles-time-zone", {tz: timezone}, function(data) {
      //Preocess the timezone in the controller function and get
      //the confirmation value here. On success, refresh the page.
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the link https://www.epochconverter.com

The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since `January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT)`, not counting leap seconds `(in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)`. Literally speaking the epoch is `Unix time 0 (midnight 1/1/1970)`, but `'epoch'` is often used as a synonym for `'Unix time'`.

You can use The function `date_default_timezone_set` in order to set the client time zone, then you can call `date()` function to get the current time.